# Excel conditional counting

Tags: excel-formula

This is a doubt that arose in my workplace, and it should be pretty straightforward.

We have two columns of numbers, say:

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

And we want to get the number of rows that have equal numbers (2), without a helping column for each comparison. We can't get a working matrix operation (wich is the way we think correct). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three more to pile on here:

Condensed array function:

1. `{=SUM(--(A1:A10=B1:B10))}`

Same function, but wrapped in a SUMPRODUCT rather than an array function:

2. `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10=B1:B10))`

Ignores blanks:

3. `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10=B1:B10)*NOT(A1:A10="")*NOT(B1:B10=""))`

Comment: Great! I moved the accepted answer from mine to yours because I kind-of despise array functions :) Thanks for this info!

Answer (score 1):

We got it using:

```
{=SUM(IF(A1:A10=B1:B10;1;0))}
```